# On Ubuntu 22.04, cannot run Android emulator and Virtualbox at same time (Guru Meditation)

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, virtualbox, kvm, ubuntu-22.04

[image]

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 OS.
I need to develop an Android application with an Ubuntu server inside a VirtualBox virtual machine.The problem is that I completely cannot run both the server and the emulator at the same time since I get the "Guru Meditation" error on VirtualBox. What should I do?

The current settings in the virtual machine are:

- Paravirtualization interface: Default
- Hardware Virtualization: Enable Nested Paging
- Nested VT-x/AMD-V: Unchecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Guru Meditation error This means that something on your host is using
> VT-x/AMD-v, which means that VirtualBox can't use it.

Have you tried to use docker for your server?
Your problem is you are trying to run two different virtualization solutions and they get in conflict.
A possible solution could be to use docker since it does not use hardware virtualization.

Comment: I've never used Docker, I'll have to try. For the server, I have an OVA file. Can it be used on Docker?

Comment: No, you install Docker, and install an image from Docker Hub, it´s easy, once I started using Docker, i got rid of all the virtual machines and locally installed servers